# Can a Factory Reset fix Malware Problem? And another question too!

Tags: security, factory-reset, malware

After factory reset my pictures, videos, and other media remained. Is it an indication of infection? Prior to the factory reset.

Can you explain why my media wasn't deleted? It was supposed to wipe out everything on the phone.

Comment: Please only include one question per question post.

Answer (score 2):

Factory resets only partially erase* the main data directory, not the internal/external storage drive (SD Card for example).

All videos, photos, music etc remain, as they are stored on the internal/external drive - only apps and app data would be deleted.

*I say partially erase, because if everything in the data directory was erased, the OS wouldn't function correctly.

Comment: A minor adjustment: Everything in the `/data` directory does in fact get erased, that's the idea behind a factory-reset. And that's why all apps and their data are gone. Only the ROM survives, with the integrated ("pre-installed") apps. Apart from that: Yes, exactly that's why media survive – unless one checks to have the SDCard wiped, too (some devices offer that).